# Show only if not exist in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with skiers and ski stations that they are skied in.

For example:

```
---------------------
   skier     station
---------------------
|    1     |    2
|    1     |    3
|    2     |    2 
---------------------
```

If I have three stations I want to show a text that say that the skier wasn't in this station.

I have:

```
 $result="SELECT * FROM skiers_and_stations WHERE skier = '$id_skier';";
 $makeResult=mysql_query($result, $conexion);
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($makeResult, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
 if ($row['station'] == '1') {   } else {echo "No here before, station 1"}; 
 if ($row['station'] == '2') {   } else {echo "No here before, station 2"}; 
 if ($row['station'] == '3') {   } else {echo "No here before, station 3"}; 
 }
```

But it doesn't work.

I want to display:

```
Skier 1 
No here before, station 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on every iteration two of the if statements will be false and go to the else statement. If you set up an array with all of the possibilities, and remove the stations they've been to, at the end you'll have a list of the stations they haven't been to.

Also, you really shouldn't use the mysql_query functions, as they're deprecated and will be removed from PHP soon. Look into [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). Also, SQL Injection on your query. For the purposes of solving your problem, I haven't made those changes.

```
$result = "SELECT * FROM skiers_and_stations WHERE skier = '$id_skier';";
$makeResult = mysql_query($result, $conexion);
$stations = array(1 => true, 2 => true, 3 => true);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($makeResult, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    unset($stations[$row['station']]);
}
foreach ($stations as $stationId => $val) {
    echo "Not here before, station $stationId";
}
```